# External JavaScript not loading and messing up embeded JavaScript in JSP

Tags: javascript, java, jsp

I have JS scripts in an external document that I import like this:

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="efectos/jquery-2.1.4.min.js"></script>
```

Not 12 hours ago that worked perfecly (last thing I checked before going to sleep). Today I wake up, open the same NetBeans project, run it (with Google Chrome), and those scripts no longer work.

I try copying the script directly into the jsp. Doesn't work. I delete the external document import (keeping the copied code in the jsp), and it works just fine.

So not only it doesn't work from the external file, when I try to "import" it it messes up what is already on the jsp...
It's not a document.ready problem too.

This has happend to me before and I haven't been able to figure out why or find an answer on the internet. It may be the stupidest thing but it's driving me crazy.

Does anyone know what can be causing this?

As asked, I share more code. My external document (named "scripts.js") has this:

```
function filter() {
  var titulo, autor, ano, precio, table, tr, tdTitulo, tdAutor, tdAno, tdPrecio, i, count;

  titulo = document.getElementById("stitulo").value.toUpperCase();
  autor = document.getElementById("sautor").value.toUpperCase();
  ano = document.getElementById("sano").value.toUpperCase();
  if(document.getElementById("sprecio").value === "") precio = 0.;
  else precio = parseFloat(document.getElementById("sprecio").value);
  table = document.getElementById("catalogo");
  tr = table.getElementsByTagName("tr");

  for (i = 1; i < tr.length; i++) {
    count = -4;
    tdTitulo = tr[i].getElementsByTagName("td")[0];
    tdAutor = tr[i].getElementsByTagName("td")[1];
    tdAno = tr[i].getElementsByTagName("td")[3];
    tdPrecio = tr[i].getElementsByTagName("td")[4];

    if (tdTitulo) {
      if (tdTitulo.innerHTML.toUpperCase().indexOf(titulo) > -1) {
        count++;
      }
    }
    if (tdAutor) {
      if (tdAutor.innerHTML.toUpperCase().indexOf(autor) > -1) {
        count++;
      }
    }
    if (tdAno) {
      if (tdAno.innerHTML.toUpperCase().indexOf(ano) > -1) {
        count++;
      }
    }
    if (tdPrecio) {
      if ((precio >= parseFloat(tdPrecio.innerHTML)) || precio === 0) {
        count++;
      }
    }
    if(count >= 0) tr[i].style.display = "";
    else tr[i].style.display = "none";
  }
}
```

My imports look like this:

```
<%@ taglib prefix="fmt" uri="http://java.sun.com/jsp/jstl/fmt" %>
<%@ taglib prefix="c" uri="http://java.sun.com/jsp/jstl/core" %>
<%@page contentType="text/html" pageEncoding="UTF-8"%>

<!DOCTYPE html>

<html>
    <head>
        <title>Música para DAWA</title>
        <meta name="description" content="Tienda online de música">
    <meta name="keywords" content="tienda,música">
    <meta name="robots" content="all">
        <link type = "text/css" rel = "stylesheet" href = "efectos/stylesheet.css"/>
        <script type="text/javascript" src="efectos/jquery-2.1.4.min.js"></script>
        <script type="text/javascript" src="efectos/scripts.js"></script>
    </head>
```

I call the function like this:

```
<div id="search">
            <label class = "text">Título:<input type="text" id="stitulo" onkeyup="filter()" /></label>
            <label class = "text">Autor:<input type="text" id="sautor" onkeyup="filter()" /></label>
            <label class = "text">Año:<input type="text" id="sano" onkeyup="filter()" size="1" /></label>
            <label class = "text">Precio máximo:<input type="text" id="sprecio" onkeyup="filter()" size="1" /></label>
        </div>
```

The weird thing that baffles me is that it was working when I closed the project and when I open it, it doesn't... unless I write the script in the .jsp.

Hope you have enough info now, but feel free to ask for more, I'm a noob.

Thanks!

Comment: Please share some code.

Comment: Does the external script show up in the sources of Google Chrome? My gut says that there's something wrong with the order that your js is in, but of course I won't know until more code is uploaded.

Comment: I updated the question. Hope you have all you need now. Thanks a lot! @Ayush Oh and yes it does show up in the "view source code" in Google Chrome, don't know if you meant that.